# Android Studio, how to see "tips(quick documentation)"?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I've been coding in Android Studio for a while now, be as in Kotlin and currently in Flutter. Whenever I am watching tutorials or lectures I see some-how they make a small window pop up that kinda shows some info. Here is a quick screenshot what I'm talking about:
[image: Exmaple Picture]

I'm just bit curious about that because I know in Flutter you can press alt+enter to wrap certain widgets in other widgets. How do I get that window up?

Kind regards,

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following shortcut while your cursor is on the right place:

For mac:

```
Control(^) + j
```

For others:

```
Ctrl+F1 or Ctrl+Q
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called *Quick Documentation*. Access it via `View -> Quick Documentation`.

Comment: As mentioned in Md Golam Rahman Tushar's answer, you can use CTRL + Q to access this.